# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium: 3.12.0, geckodriver: 0.21.0, Firefox: 52 (32bit).

I'm getting error like:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused

Am I using correct combination? And if I want to use Firefox 52 and Selenium 3.12 then which geckodriver version should use?

Comment: The error stack trace would have been helpful to analyze the issue. Update the question with error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer from one of the `geckodriver` developers:

> We aren't supporting Firefox 52ESR anymore and `geckodriver 0.20.1`
>   doesn't work with that version. See the release notes for minimal
>   Firefox versions.
>
> Please note that Firefox 60ESR is available in the meantime, and you
>   should  upgrade.

[Link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1280) to the conversation.

So, you have to upgrade your Firefox.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, I upgraded Firefox to 61.0(64 bit) but still getting the error. "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused"